# SharpSVN - no revision number at SvnUpdateResult after export

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

What I would like to do is to export file with HEAD revision and get actual revision number for this exported file.

I am using this method from SvnClient

```
 Export(SvnTarget, String, SvnExportArgs, SvnUpdateResult)
```

But SvnUpdateResult shows Revision with value -1

How to sort this out?

Comment: Can you extend your snippet to a working example. I'm unable to reproduce your problem and can't find a reason why it would fail (without hacking the server to perform nonstandard)

Comment: Sorry, do not have sample any more. My workaround was to use GetInfo and then looking at LastChangeRevision. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What is your SvnTarget. If you pass a local path and no explicit revision there is no single revision that specifies your entire working copy. Everything would be exported as in your working copy.

If you pass a Url, or a path with an explicit revision (e.g. Head) you should get a revision in the update result.

Comment: target is SvnTarget.FromUri. Uri created with URL to remote file.